# Every element of a local ring is a sum of two units iff the cardinality of the ring is less than twice the cardinality of units

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, local-rings

Is it true that every element of a local ring with unity can be written as a sum of two units iff the cardinality of the ring is strictly less than twice the cardinality of units of the ring?

It is known that the unique maximal ideal of the local ring consists entirely of non-unit elements. Using this fact how can we arrive at a resolution of the above question. I think it is true. Does it follow simply from the fact that any such representation of a non-unit is unique? Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not hold in $\mathbb{F}_2$, since $1 \neq 1+1$. If $k$ is a field besides $\mathbb{F}_2$, pick some $b \in k \setminus \{0,1\}$. Then $(x-b) + b$ expresses $x$ as a sum of two units for all $x \neq b$, and $b = (b-1)+1$ is also a sum of two units.

Next, let $R$ be a commutative local ring with maximal ideal $m$. First, suppose $R/m$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$. Then we cannot write $1$ as a sum of two units of $R$, or else we would be able to write $1$ as a sum of two units in $R/m$. Thus, $R$ does not have the desired property. On the other hand, suppose $R/m$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$. Then, let $x \in R$ be arbitrary, and write $\overline{x}$ (the image of $x$ in the residue field) as a sum of two units in $R/m$. This means that there exist units $a,b \in R$ such that $x-(a+b) \in m$. Let $y = x-(a+b)$. Then $x = (y + a) + b$ expresses $x$ as a sum of two units.

We conclude that a local ring $R$ with maximal ideal $m$ has the property that each element is a sum of two units if and only if $R/m$ is not isomorphic to $\mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: I assume here that we're working with commutative local rings. If they are allowed to be noncommutative, things might get a bit more complicated.